# How is "try out" used when referring to something already mentioned?

Tags: pronouns, phrasal-verbs

I wrote:

> I can say without a single doubt that both games are worth trying <s>them</s> out.

My teacher crossed "them" out. Now I need to know why my sentence was wrong.

Comment: Your teacher is correct. "Them" and "both games" refer to the same thing. You only need one of them. "Both games are worth trying out" or "They are worth trying out" or "It is worth trying them out" or "It is worth trying both games out". I am not posting this as an answer because I don't know what grammar rule this falls under, but I would like to provide you a little bit of explanation in case nobody else answers : )

Answer (score 1):

It's not about "trying out", it's about "worth".

"Worth" (in this case) takes the subcategorisation frame (it can have others):

> worth VP-ing NP

However the "NP" (which is the object of the VP-ing) is deleted if it is already in the matrix clause (the containing clause).

> The game is worth playing.
>
> The town is worth visiting.
>
> This speaker is worth waiting for.

When the object is not expressed in  the matrix clause, (most commonly because the dummy subject "it" is used), it needs to be expressed in the dependent clause:

> It is worth playing the game.
>
> It is worth visiting the town.
>
> It is worth waiting for the speaker.